# How to connect to LDAP server using c#

Tags: c#, ldap

I am trying to test the connectivity with the LDAP server as below code  but I didn't succeed.

Can anyone tell how to connect.

```
 bool validres= ValidateLDAPUser("LDAP://dp01.XXX.XXX", "LDAP_account", "LDAP_password");
 Response.Write(validres + " <p>Ad Auth fail</p>");
static bool ValidateLDAPUser(string ldapserver, string userId, string password)
{
    try
    {
        using (var ldapConnection = new LdapConnection(
                new LdapDirectoryIdentifier($"{ldapserver}")))
        {
            ldapConnection.AuthType = AuthType.Basic;
            ldapConnection.AutoBind = false;
            ldapConnection.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 15);
            
            var ldapUserId = $"uid={userId}";
            var credential = new NetworkCredential(ldapUserId, password);
            ldapConnection.Bind(credential);
            Console.WriteLine("Successfully authenticated to ldap server " + ldapserver);
            return true;
        }

    }
    catch (LdapException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(("Error with ldap server " + ldapserver + e.ToString()));
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is not working exactly? Try to use  `NetworkCredential` class with the specified user name, password, and domain.

Comment: I have try to use with the specified username ,password and doman as below :  var credential = new NetworkCredential("uid=ldap_account,ou=people,dc=XXX.com",
                    "ldap_pwd");   //but still not success

Comment: I mean try as `var credential = new NetworkCredential("LDAP_account", "LDAP_password","LDAP_account_domain");`,

Comment: I have try to use as you said ,but still not success

Comment: Do you get exception or something?

Comment: @georgetovrea When asking for help, avoid phrases like "not success" or "doesn't work" since that can literally mean anything. If your computer caught fire, that still means "not success". Tell us what *did* happen. Was there an exception? Did it run to the end without doing anything at all?

Comment: it's  error in ldapConnection.Bind(credential); and  get the error msg is "System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.LdapException: LDAP is unavailable。" but i have check the ldap server from ldp.exe is work